# How create a react-native custom view with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to create a custom view with react-native-modal in my custom view:

```
type Props = {isVisible: boolean;setVisible: void }
<Modal isVisible={props.visible}......>
<Button title="colse" onPress={()=> props.setVisible}>
```

Then in my page:

```
const [isVisible,setVisible]= React.useState(false)
const onClick= () =>{setVisible(!isVisible)}
<MyView visible={isVisible} setVisible={onClick}/>
```

But when I click the button, nothing happens and there is no error.

If I change the code like this:

```
const [isVisible,setVisible]= React.useState(true)
```

the dialog will be shown at first, but cannot close.

I hope someone can give me an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
<Button title="colse" onPress={()=> props.setVisible()}>


const [isVisible,setVisible] = React.useState(false)
const onClick= () => {setVisible(!isVisible)}
<MyView visible={isVisible} setVisible={onClick}/>
```

Comment: Thank！ i insert () after the method Then it can run！

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by **updating the state based on the previous state**.

like:

```
const onClick = () => {setVisible(prevState => !prevState)}
```